# ivy intelliJ proxy connection error

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy, ivy, intellij-14

I am using `IvyIDEA` to resolve module dependencies through `ivy` on `IntelliJ`.
But when I tried `IvyIDEA` -> resolve for all modules, the process is halting due to proxy setting. In the event log, I could see error like:

> ERROR: Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.5/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.5.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect)
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect*

I have tested the HTTP Proxy Setting for `IntelliJ`, it shows "Connection successful" for check connection.

It seems the proxy setting in `IntelliJ` is not properly passed to `IvyIDEA`, so what's the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)